# How to setup lvm to cache /root on 18.04?

Tags: grub2, 18.04, ssd, lvmcache

I have two drives and can use lvmcache to cache the hard drive with the SSD with 16.04.  However, when I follow the same process with 18.04, I can create the lvmcache but when I reboot, I get the Grub2 screen and prompt.

How do I setup lvmcache to cache /root on 18.04?

Answer (score 1):

Here is what worked for me:

1. I used the alternate ISO to install so I could manually set partition the drives and set up LVM.
2. On my hard drive, I created a partition for EFI and another partition formated to Ext4 mounted to /boot.
3. I created my volume group and logical volumes for /root and /swap on the remaining space on my hard drive.
4. I expanded my volume group to include my SSD, then set up logical volumes for the cache data and cache meta data.
5. After completing the install & rebooting, I followed the steps from Jethro's blog (http://scyu.logdown.com/posts/519001-ubuntu-lvmcache-setup).  I skipped directly to the lvconvert steps since the logical volumes had already been created on the SSD.  I also removed "--cachepolicy mg".
6. I also followed Johannes Bauer's advice adding "copy_exec /usr/sbin/cache_check" to /usr/share/initramfs-tools/hooks/lvm2 and making lvm2 executable.
7. Then I updated initramfs (update-initramfs -u -k all) then updated (apt-get update) and upgraded (apt-get full-upgrade).

I may have done more that I needed to, but I've followed these steps to set up three machines running 18.04 with SSD caching through lvmcache.